# Android Intent Sharing From Gridview

Tags: android, gridview, android-intent, share

Creating an a app, where I store bunch of photos in the drawable folder, When the user longpress on a photo brings up a menu, one of the options is to share.I can get the contextmenu up, but have no clue how to share from the grid menu.

I also have the expand it is bring up single image in own view and can share from there.

**But when the user selects the Image from the gridview I have no Idea how to share that one.**

this is the method i call when user selects share option

```
public Intent intentShare() {    
        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/jpeg");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.here/drawable/"+share.putExtra("id", lastPosition)));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
        return share;
}
```

I have seen this possible option/solution on a couple of other questions

```
Bitmap icon = mBitmap;
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpeg");
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
try {
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
} catch (IOException e) {                       
        e.printStackTrace();
}
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/temporary_file.jpg"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

But I have no idea how to initialize mBitmap if that works ?

The entire code can be found here:  http://pastie.org/private/gdpyn2t55h0gp1vp1kika

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `Bitmap` from resource using code like this:

```
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mThumbIds[lastPosition]);
```

now you can share it as you share in Expanded view.